# Filter SiteTree TreeDropdownField() in SilverStripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

How do I filter the results of the `SiteTree` pages so as to only get one with a ClassName of `ProductPage`?

Here are the relevant portions of code -

```
static $has_one = array('ProductLinkPagesID' => 'SiteTree');
```

and here

```
$ProductLinkPages = new TreeDropdownField('ProductLinkPagesID', 'Related Products Link', 'SiteTree');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to keep the tree structure, but only allow people to select 'ProductPage' pages, you can use a TreeDropdownField and disable all other nodes: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-TreeDropdownField.html#_setDisableFunction.

```
$tree->setDisableFunction(function($item) {
    return ( ! $item instanceof ProductPage);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the results needed are from the SiteTree is pages but only one type of page - ProductPage, using `DropdownField` is better here along with `ProductPage::get()->map()` -

```
$ProductLinkPages = DropdownField::create('ProductLinkPagesID', 'Related Products Link', ProductPage::get()->map());
```

Thanks to user4694959

Answer (score 1):

TreeDropdownField cannot render a Tree if it is filtered.

You'll need to use vanilla **DropdownField** - or another solution if you find numbers too big an issue for trawling through a dropdown list. Although by default the CMS uses jquery.chozen to aid with this.

Comment: Great thanks, DropdownField is much better to use here along with ProductPage::get()->map()